# How to get list of functions in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, function

```
    <?php

    function funct_one(){
        //do something
    }
    function funct_two(){
        //do something
    }
    function funct_three(){
        //do something
    }
    function funct_four(){
        //do something
    }

     $func_list=array();
    ?>
```

thats an example code

i want a list of all functions, something like this,

```
$func_list=array('funct_one','funct_two','funct_three','funct_four');
```

i want this array to generated itself on load .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `get_defined_functions()` like

```
$fun_arr = get_defined_functions();
print_r($fun_arr['user']);
```

See this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php)

Comment: print_r($fun_arr['user']);

thank you.. :)

Comment: If so, then `print_r(get_defined_functions()['user'])`

Comment: @ManjunathHegde its better to accept `Wayne Whitty` ans bec its first ans rather than me

Comment: @ Alma Do Mundo : its a syntax error .. 
@Gautam i choose your answer brother..

Comment: Acc to `SO` the first correct ans will be accepted

Comment: @ Gautam:
with your answer i got this :-Array ( [0] => funct_one [1] => funct_two [2] => funct_three [3] => funct_four ) ;<-this is what i wa looking for,
and with Wayne Whitty's answer i got this:-array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "funct_one" [1]=> string(9) "funct_two" [2]=> string(11) "funct_three" [3]=> string(10) "funct_four" }

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo it will leads you syntax error if it was php version < 5.4

Comment: @Gautam3164 - yes, i know :( And to be honest - I can't understand why maintain 5.3 or lower :\

Answer (score 5):

[get_defined_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php)

> get_defined_functions — Returns a multidimensional array containing a
>   list of all defined functions, both built-in (internal) and
>   user-defined. The internal functions will be accessible via
>   $arr["internal"], and the user defined ones using $arr["user"]

Example:

```
function funct_four(){
    //do something
}

$arr = get_defined_functions();
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Just few seconds fast...You got the result.+1 for you

Comment: Always wondered why in one case such answer (nearly link to manual) will be downvoted -3 and worse and in other cases - upvoted to +5 and better, while it always should be just a comment I guess :p Will not upvote/dowvote anyway :p

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo A comment isn't an answer though :p He asked a very specific question and it had a very specific answer. In my opinion, posting it as a comment would have defeated the purpose of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Link to manual is a specific answer? :p Not sure. Nevermind, just trying to clarify the criteria for myself (as I've seen many samples where such questions/answers were downvoted seriously instead)

Comment: Because this question have to be rather closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function myrow($id, $data)
{
    return "<tr><th>$id</th><td>$data</td></tr>\n";
}

$arr = get_defined_functions();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```